# Why do I get a PhotoImage error when I put my GUI into a thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to come up with a system to display a splash page while the first page of my main GUI(both made with tkinter) loads up. I read online that tkinter had to have all the graphic commands for a particular tkinter window in the same thread. So my idea to display the splash screen in a Toplevel window on a second thread while the main page loads up on the first thread(the main page is hidden while splash page is shown using `withdraw()`), wouldn't work out. So I decided to have separate GUI's for the splash and the main application. The main page will initialize while the splash is displayed and after that, the splash would be destroyed and the main page would reappear using `deiconify()`. I tried the idea using 2 simple GUI's and it worked but when I implemented it on my code for the splash page, for some reason, I got the following error.

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:/Jovan/Captain!!Project/Captain_repo/rough.py", line 7, in import_
    import rough1
  File "c:\Jovan\Captain!!Project\Captain_repo\rough1.py", line 71, in <module>
    splash.display()
  File "c:\Jovan\Captain!!Project\Captain_repo\rough1.py", line 56, in display
    self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x04EF02B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jovan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

I found questions online with similar errors but they all suggested things like the image passed to PhotoImage was not a PIL image, which did not help me much. The splash page works fine if I simply execute it or import it from another file but when I put it into a thread, I get the above error. Here is a reproducible code for my problem.

```py
'''The code is executed here.'''
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading


def import_() :
    import rough1

# creating and starting thread to display splash
splash_thread = threading.Thread(target=import_)
splash_thread.daemon = True
splash_thread.start()

# Main GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",root.quit())
root.title("rough")
root.update()
tk.Button(root,text="Hey").pack()
tk.Label(root,text="Hello").pack()
root.update_idletasks()

# Re-displays the main GUI if the splash has been destroyed.
print(threading.active_count())
while threading.active_count() == 2 :
    print("loading...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
else :
    root.deiconify()
    print(threading.active_count())

root.mainloop()
```

The code for splash page:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class SplashScreen(ThemedTk) :
    def __init__(self,**kwargs) :
        ThemedTk.__init__(self,theme="black",**kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        # self.title("[GAME INITIALIZING...]")
        self.splash()
        self.update()
        self.window()

    def splash(self) :
        self.image1 = Image.open('project_pics\\splash.png')

    def window(self) :
        width, height = self.image1.size
        setwinwidth = (self.winfo_screenwidth()-width)//2
        setwinheight = (self.winfo_screenheight()-height)//2
        self.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{setwinwidth}+{setwinheight}")
        self.update()

    def display(self) :
        print("splash_Displayed!!")
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        splash_canvas = tk.Canvas(self,width=screen_width,height=screen_height)
        splash_canvas.pack()
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image1)
        self.update_idletasks()
        splash_canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.tkimage,anchor="nw")
        splash_canvas.image = self.tkimage
        self.update_idletasks()
        splash_canvas.create_text(200,34,text="[LOADING]...PLEASE WAIT",font=("small fonts",20),fill="white")
        progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=900, mode='determinate',style="Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        progressbar.place(x=450,y=25)
        progressbar.start()
        self.after(5050,self.destroy)
        self.mainloop()


splash = SplashScreen()
splash.display()
```

So these are my queries. **Why do I get the above error** and **how do I fix it**??

Comment: `Toplevel` is not separated part and it should be use in main thread.

Comment: error first show you `main thread is not in main loop` becaue Tkinter should run only one `mainloop` and it should run it in main thread. So your real problem is not `PhotoImage` but `mainloop` and using thread. Do you really need to use thread?

Comment: @furas The main page of my GUI doesn't load up very quickly. So you can see something like a glitch on the screen for a second, while it gets set up. I wanted to hide that by loading the main page while the splash screen shows. That's why I used a thread to do both parallelly.

Comment: what so big do you load in this page? if you load some file then you can load it in separated thead but later you should add it to tkinter window in main thread. And at the same time splash screen should be display in main thread

Comment: I don't load anything external but I need to create several widgets and resize the background image to fit screen size, so its not very fast.

Comment: ```time.sleep()```  the splash page so that your main window can have some time to load